# Pagination on select query metamug

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, metamug

This is my current resource file. I'm using [MySQL Query Pagination Feature](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">
<Request method="GET">
    <Query>
        select * from tbl_task_master 
        LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset
    </Query>
</Request>
</Resource>
```

`https://api.metamug.com/checklist/v1.0/task?offset=0&limit=50`

It's fetching all the records. I want to paginate and only get a subset. How do I make the request with Metamug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement pagination you need to make use of `limit` and `offset` attributes of `Query` tag and then you can pass it any parameter name that you'll be using in your request.
Let's say your [pagination parameters](https://metamug.com/docs/request-parameters.php#pagination-parameters) are **`l`** and **`o`** for limit and offset respectively *(though not a good naming convention)*
Your `resource` file will now look like

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">
    <Request method="GET">
       <Param name="l" type="number" required="true" min="5" max="20"/>
       <Param name="o" type="number" required="true" min="0" max="100"/>
       <Sql id="tasks" limit="l" offset="o">
          select * from tbl_task_master 
       </Sql>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```

Declaring

> ```
> <Param name="l" type="number" required="true" min="5" max="20"/>
> <Param name="o" type="number" required="true" min="0" max="100"/>
> ```

Is optional but as you can see we can add more constraints we do initialize them.See this for [more on `Param` tag and validation](https://metamug.com/docs/request-parameters.php#validation-attributes)

Comment: I think `LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset` in the query shouldn't be needed anymore.

Comment: @Sorter yes you're right.. my bad. after making use of `offset` and `limit` attribute you don't to write them in query again. I've updated my answer

Comment: Also to confirm my api call becomes `https://api.metamug.com/checklist/v1.0/task?o=0&l=50` as per your answer.